# Быстрый выбор числа из массива

Tags: java, c++, производительность

Здравствуйте, нужна помощь в одном, на первый взгляд не очень сложном вопросе:
есть некоторый массив с некоторыми числами

```
int[] delims_indxs = {12, 13, 15, 20, 24};
```

а также некоторый промежуток (например 14 - 20), вопрос в том, как можно вытащить из массива первое встречающееся в промежутке число (для приведенного примера этим числом будет 15)? проблема конечно несложная, но всякие конструкции типа

```
int bit;
for(int i=14; i<=20; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < delims_indxs.length; j++)
    if(delims_indxs[j]==i)
        bit = l;
if (bit!=-1) break;
}
```

очень плохо сказываются на быстродействии потому что данную процедуру нужно делать много-много тысяч раз для разных промежутков. можно конечно использовать не массив, а чтонибудь другое, но суть такая же- найти первое число из промежутка

Comment: Видимо надо наоборот. 

Каждое число массива сравнивать с границами диапазона. При попадании закончить цикл.

Comment: За 5 минут 6 ответов. У всех одновременно организовался перерыв?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, зачем Вам нужно два цикла, если можно обойтись одним.

```
int bit = -1;
int mmax = 20;
int mmin = 14;
for(int j = 0; j < delims_indxs.length; j++)
    if(delims_indxs[j] >= mmin && delims_indxs[j] <= mmax) {
        bit = l;
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Если быстродействие важно, и операция поиска будет выполняться много раз, вам стоит произвести предварительную обработку данных.

Например, вы можете отсортировать данные в массиве, и использовать двоичный поиск. Скорость поиска возрастёт с `O(n)` до `O(log n)`.

Вы также можете использовать структуру данных типа `std::map` со встроенной функцией [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) в C++.

В Java можно использовать SortedSet и функцию [subSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet%28E,%20E%29).

Comment: @VladD, это похоже первое, отличное от тривиальных решение в рамках данного tea-break (судя по количеству и частоте ответов).

--

IMHO по условию задачии требуется первое число из диапазона.  В худшем случае n циклов. 

Вот если бы стояла задача поиска для *многих* диапазонов, тогда сортировка имела бы смысл.

Comment: @avp: хм, автор заявляет, что

> данную процедуру нужно делать много-много тысяч раз для разных промежутков

Я посчитал, что временем на предварительную подготовку данных можно пренебречь.

Comment: @pavlik_uhuhu: пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD, действительно. Наверное изменил свой вопрос уже после моего комментария.

Тогда согласен, сортировка и двоичный поиск (в худшем случае 2 двоичных поиска) для каждого диапазона.

Answer (score 1):

Если указан просто интервал, то разве нельзя проверять попадание в него числа элементарным способом

```
_min=2;
_max=10;
if ((num > _min) && (num < _max)) {
      .....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Усложняете

```
int j=0;
for(;j<delims_indxs.length;j++)
  if(delims_indxs[j]>=min&&delims_indxs[j]<=max)break;
if(j>=delims_indxs.length){   //число не найдено
}
else{    //j - номер найденного
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что пришло в голову:

```
int bit;
  for(int j = 0; j < delims_indxs.length; j++)
    if(delims_indxs[j] > min && delims_indxs[j] < max)
        bit = l;
if (bit!=-1) break;
}
```

в данном случае (промежуток 14 - 20) количество итераций уменьшается в 7 раз.

Comment: у Вас в коде есть две ошибки. Хотя если правильно задать min/max, то все будет ок. Вторая ошибка может проявляться в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Я просто скопировал изначальный код автора, и проглядел эти моменты.  

----  

То, что я хоть немного начал разбираться в с++ для меня уже хорошо :) А ошибки со временем уйдут :)

----  

Если исправлю эти ошибки, то ответ будет похож на Ваш. А это плагиат. Так что приму их с честью.

Comment: подсказки

 - использовать имена `min` и `max` плохо, особенно, если прописать `using namespace std;`
 - условия нужно заменить на `>=` и `<=` - у автора вопроса диапазоны "включая".

Comment: Люди в сообществе говорят, что использовать __using namespace std__ не стоит, так что я уже приучаю себя избегать этого. Да и min с max'ом я использовал чисто для пояснения. Но все равно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Храните не в массиве, а в дереве, для поиска используйте lower_bound

схематично как-то так:

```
set<...> delims_indxs 
range r[14-20];

iterator i = std::lower_bound( begin(delims_indxs), end(delims_indxs), r[0] )
```

Comment: А это Java?

Comment: схематичный с++, но думаю в Java можно аналогично

Comment: Дерево упростит жизнь если вставка осуществляется часто. Вставка в массив линейна, в дерево логарифмична.